# Is finding cache size possible with information given?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache, cpu, memory-hardware, cpu-pipelines

An 8-way set-associative cache is used in a computer in which the real memory size is 2<sup>22</sup> bytes. The line size is 16 bytes, and there are 2<sup>6</sup> lines per set. 
A) What is the size of the cache in bytes?

What I (think) I understand: 
Cache line and cache block are synonymous.
The textbook says that an n-way set-associative cache has n blocks(lines) per set. That conflicts with the next sentence that says "there are 2<sup>6</sup> lines per set." Is this problem incorrect or are my assumptions wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An n-way set associative cache can store n different entries for a given index in the cache array.  So the 8-way acts like an 8x multiplier as compared with a direct mapped cache (1-way set associative).

So, I would take it that the line size of 2<sup>4</sup> with 2<sup>6</sup> lines per set and 2<sup>3</sup>-way set associative is 2<sup>13</sup> or 8k bytes.

A next question might be how big are the tags that are stored in the associations?   22 (from the address space) - 4 (for cache line size) - 6 (the number of entries in the array), means that a tag size of 12 bits is needed.